# How can I access my javascript after webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have experience in Javascript and `jQuery`, but I am new to `webpack`.

I have a file called test1.js:

```
exports.func1 = function() {
    window.alert('hello from func 1');
};
```

I then have index.js, which contains the following:

```
import test1 from "./test1"
```

My webpack.config.js contains:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), //folder to put the output file
  },
};
```

I have included app.js into my webpage and that is fine, no errors in console about file cannot be found.  I want to call `func1()` from a button click, for example, `<button onclick="func1()">Test</button>`.

When I do this I get "func1 is not defined" in console output.  Webpack doesn't show any errors when I run it, so it must be the way I am calling the function somehow.

I must be doing something, or not doing something, really stupid.  Can someone help as I seem to be going round in circles?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's because test1 is the exported object. func1 is a property of test1.

```
test1.func1() will invoke the function
```

You could also import it by destructuring. Try the following:

```
import { func1 } from './test1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change test1.js to:

```
export default () => {
    window.alert('hello from func 1');
};
```

Then in your index.js:

```
export { default as test1 } from "./test1"
```

If you want to consume in HTML you should build a library and update your webpack like below:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), //folder to put the output file
    library: 'myApp',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
};
```

Now your function is exported and should be available for usage.

Comment: I assume I then call test1() from the HTML.  I tried your modifications and they did not work.  I get the same thing, even if I put test1();

Comment: Didn;t notice that you consume in HTML. I've updated it with library build in webpack